# Как менять дату на MacOS monterey через терминал?

Tags: консоль, macos

Пишу небольшую утилиту для себя и хочу поменять дату на маке. Команды **"date 120520302021"** или "**sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com**" не работают. На первую пишет "**date: settimeofday (timeval): Operation not permitted**", а на вторую "**sudo: ntpdate: command not found**", причём время надо менять как на конкретное так и с сервера apple например(как во второй команде). На мак пересел совсем недавно и команд консоли толком не знаю, буду очень благодарен, если кто подскажет. Заранее большое спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы изменить текущую дату, используйте `sudo` и год в двузначном формате

```
sudo date 1205203021
```

Для синхронизации времени с сервером используйте `sntp`, так как `ntpdate` недоступна в MacOS начиная с Mojave

```
sudo sntp -sS time.apple.com
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло